# Mapserver GeoJSON input

Tags: geojson, mapserver

Is it possible for MapServer to read GeoJSON file and serve it as a layer in the .map file? 
Like how it can be done with shapefiles as shown below:

```
LAYER
    Name 'land'
    TYPE POLYGON
    DATA 'path/to/shapefile'
END
```

In [MapServer documentation](https://mapserver.org/input/vector/ogr.html#what-data-formats-are-supported), seems like OGR connection can read GeoJSON files but I couldn't find any example online.

Comment: `and serve it as a layer` ~ certainly MapServer can serve GeoJSON, it doesn't have to be the input, as a WFS output ~ here's an example http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&typenames=ENERGY_STATUS_2016&srsName=epsg:4326&bbox=2.3319787109375003,32.20465253906251,3.4415978515625003,33.31427167968751,EPSG:4326&outputformat=application/json;%20subtype=geojson& Input in this example is a postgresql database

Comment: The example you give doesn't tell us anything about the output, only the input for the layer.  The output could be an image (if we have a WMS configured) as part of a GetMap request, or GeoJSON (if we have a WFS configured).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr;

> Is it possible for MapServer to read GeoJSON file and serve it as a layer

Yes, the below requests use a GeoJSON input (taken from my example comment).

[MapServer WFS output in GeoJSON with GeoJSON as input](http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/mdtest/ows?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=ms:ENERGY_STATUS_2016&STARTINDEX=0&COUNT=1000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&outputformat=JSON)

[MapServer WFS output in GML with GeoJSON as input](http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/mdtest/ows?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=ms:ENERGY_STATUS_2016&STARTINDEX=0&COUNT=1000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326)

For configuring input you need in your map file LAYER:

```
    CONNECTION "data/ows.json"
    CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
```

For layer projection I used:

```
    PROJECTION
        # https://mapserver.org/mapfile/projection.html#projection
        # The following syntax may be used in LAYERs that are OGR connections, shapefile layers or raster layers:
        AUTO
    END
```

I also have:

```
    CLASSITEM "Status_1"
    LABELITEM "Status_1"

    METADATA
        "GML_FEATUREID" "fid"
        "GML_INCLUDE_ITEMS" "all"
        "GML_TYPES" "auto"
        "OWS_TITLE" "Energy generation status (2016)"
    END

    STATUS ON
    TYPE POINT
```

and for outputting GeoJSON as part of a WFS, irrespective of what the input vector data is, you need something like:

```
MAP
    OUTPUTFORMAT
        NAME "JSON"
        DRIVER "OGR/GEOJSON"
        EXTENSION "json"
        FORMATOPTION "FORM=SIMPLE"
        FORMATOPTION "LCO:COORDINATE_PRECISION=8"
        FORMATOPTION "LCO:DESCRIPTION=This should be GeoJSON 2008; the projection may not be in CRS:84, but if not, there should be a crs: member telling you what projection has been used"
        FORMATOPTION "LCO:NATIVE_DATA=YES"
        FORMATOPTION "LCO:WRITE_BBOX=YES"
        FORMATOPTION "STORAGE=stream"
        MIMETYPE "application/json; subtype=geojson"
    END
    WEB
        METADATA
            "OWS_ABSTRACT" "This is a test web service"
            "OWS_ACCESSCONSTRAINTS" ""
            "WFS_enable_request" "*"
            "OWS_FEES" "none"
            "OWS_KEYWORDLIST" "test,testing,123"
            "OWS_SERVICE_ONLINERESOURCE" ""
            "OWS_TITLE" "Testing capabilities"
            "WFS_GETFEATURE_FORMATLIST" "JSON"
        END
    END
    LAYER
        # your input vector data
    END
...
END
```

Comment: Thank you, managed to get it working with your example. Just another question, what if the GeoJSON contains multiple geometry types?

Comment: @ssaga I don't know.  Possibly you'd need to set up more than one layer for your input geojson one for each geometry type

Answer (score 0):

according to https://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=106527

the mapfile syntax is

```
  CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
  CONNECTION "/path/to/file.json"
  DATA "OGRGeoJSON"
```

not tested but seems correct (OGRGeoJSON is the geomtery name provided by ogrinfo  )